# Was Sirius Black Ever Vindicated?

Tags: harry-potter

As per the Harry Potter books (1-5) we know that Sirius Black was on the run from the Ministry of Magic for the supposed killings of twelve muggles and one wizard by the name of Peter Pettigrew. Many muggles declared that they have witnessed this, thus the Ministry of Magic have been trying to capture Black. Prior to Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban, Sirius was already on the run for twelve years. After then, he has either been hiding or at Number Twelve Grimmauld Place. In Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Black was executed by none other than Bellatrix Lestrange. Up to this point, the Ministry was after him.

Was the Black name ever vindicated before or after this incident?